# Базовые данные в localStorage по умолчанию при посещении страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

При выборе опций, данные успешно записываются в localStorage. В моём случае это 2 варианта. Вариант 1 и вариант 2. Поэтому, после перезагрузки страницы, последний выбранный вариант сохраняется. Однако, столкнулся с трудностью добавления базовых значений, при условии, что пользователь, ничего не выбрал. Как решить данную задачу?
Пытался реализовать через "или" в getItem '||', не получилось.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#choose').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        var txt = jQuery('#choose').text();
       localStorage.setItem("choose", jQuery('#choose').text());
});
    }); 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var ids = ["choose"];
    for (var id of ids) {
    var span = document.getElementById(id);
    span.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(id);
    (function(id, span) {
      span.addEventListener("change", function() {
        localStorage.setItem(id, span.innerHTML);
      });
    })(id, span);
  } 
});
```

[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex45678/gyz4rch9/19/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось! :) Сделал, вот так:  `span.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(id)|| document.getElementById("basic").innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял что требуется, то решение скорее всего будет такое

```
span.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(id) || "Вы еще ничего не выбрали";
```

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, только в качестве этого базового значения мне нужно выводить тег с динамическим содержанием `span`, текст, в примере я его обозначил, как `basic`. А текст, который нужно вывести - "По умолчанию"..

Comment: @lancho  если одно из решений правильное, то примите его